# Как создать поле модели Джанго, содержащее дату создания объекта + порядковый номер?

Tags: python, django

Всем привет!

Я создаю проект интернет-магазина на Джанго и одно из условий в ТЗ поставило меня в тупик.
По заданию, номер заказа должен добавляться автоматически и состоять из даты создания заказа + номера заказа за текущий день (т.е. на следующий день, отсчет этих номеров начнется с начала).

Как то так: ddmmyyyy + num(unique for day).

Может кто то из Вас знает, как это реализовать и сможет мне подсказать?

Comment: Загрузить из БД предыдущий созданный заказ этого месяца, вытащить из него num, прибавить к num единичку, соединить с сегодняшей датой и готово

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал вот так. Может кому-то пригодится.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import datetime

class Order(models.Model):

    def get_num(date=datetime.now()):
        date = date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        if Order.objects.all().last():
            last_order = Order.objects.all().last()
            if last_order.number[0:8] == date:
                num = int(last_order.number[8::]) + 1
            else:
                num = 1
        else:
            return f'{date}1'
        return(f'{date}{num}')

    number = models.CharField(max_length=12, default=get_num, verbose_name='номер заказа')
    ...
```